Optimisation: Constraint not being met, how do I fix this?
I am trying to optimise the premium charged to customers for profit, whilst targeting an overall conversion/retention rate. However, the overall retention target constraint does not seem to be me in the final output when I run the script. For example, when I pass the optimised premium output through the propensity model, the average does not equal the target of 80% (equals 47% instead of target of 80%).
Can I get advice on how to more appropriately allow for the overall target retention rate, and just as important how to ensure I have optimised correctly? Thanks
Here is my script:
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
Sample data for policy premiums, policy cost prices, and an initial guess for premiums*
cost_prices = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400])
initial_premiums = np.array([110, 210, 310, 410])

Elasticity model
def propensity_to_renew(premium):
    return np.exp(-0.01 * (premium - 100))

Objective function to maximize total profit
def objective(premiums, cost_prices):
    propensities = propensity_to_renew(premiums)
    profit = np.sum((premiums - cost_prices) * propensities)
    return -profit 

Constraint function for target retention rate
def retention_constraint(premiums):
    propensities = propensity_to_renew(premiums)
    target_retention = 0.8  
    return np.mean(propensities) - target_retention

Bounds for premiums
bounds = [(80, 200), (180, 300), (280, 400), (380, 500)]

Define constraints for the optimizer
constraints = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': retention_constraint}]

Perform the optimization
result = opt.minimize(objective, initial_premiums, args=(cost_prices,), 
                      bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

optimal_premiums = result.x
optimal_profit = -result.fun

print("Optimal Premiums:", optimal_premiums)
print("Optimal Profit:", optimal_profit)


Don't see any problem here. Looks fine. What's the expected output (manually)?

Ahh, I got it working. The lower bounds I set prevented the optimised premiums from being low enough to achieve a target retention of 80%, the highest retention I could hit was 47%.
